# With styled-components, how to inherit all props from div component and convert it to input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

In this case **Box** is a **div** and I want to convert it to **input** type.

```
const Input = styled(Box) as styled.input`max-width: 4rem`;
```

Comment: Do you want to share the Box's style with the Input, that's it?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply polymorph the styled component using `polymorphic prop`.
For more informations try this link: https://styled-components.com/docs/api#as-polymorphic-prop